# Does rooting erase anything?

Tags: rooting

If I root my android phone (just so I can get access to Wifi Tethering, etc.) will that erase anything on the phone (apps, data, etc.)?

Will it change anything other than the ability to run app(s) as rooted?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> will that erase anything on the phone

Rooting itself should not erase anything (except for, maybe, temporary files created during the process). However, on some devices rooting requires to first unlock the bootloader -- and *that* usually includes a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) (which means: *all* data and user-installed apps are gone -- which you can work around on Android 4.0+ performing an `adb backup –apk –shared –all –f /path/to/backup.ab` *before* performing the unlock, and `adb restore /path/to/backup.ab` afterwards, as Compro01 pointed out in below comment).

> Will it change anything other than the ability to run app(s) as rooted?

Yes.¹ As the necessary binaries (usually `su`, `SuperUser.apk`/`SuperSU.apk`, and `busybox` with all its symlinks) are pushed to the `/system` partition (which otherwise is mounted read-only), it will change that partition. Might sound trivial now, but the thing is: some [ota-update](/questions/tagged/ota-update)s (and other updates shipping directly from the manufacturer/provider) first compare the partitions checksum. If that doesn't match (and it won't after rooting), updates might be refused/failing.

On the other hand: if those updates wouldn't fail, you might lose [root](/questions/tagged/root) when they are applied. If they include a full `/system` image, that is.

---

¹ <sub>**Update:** With [Magisk](/tags/magisk/info) the changes described here are not applied to the system partition.</sub>

Comment: For dealing with the factory reset, the simplest method on recent android versions (4.0 and newer) is just to use the `adb backup` command.  `adb backup –apk –shared –all –f /where/you/want/the/file` (backs up your apps and all user data) followed by `adb restore /where/you/put/the/file` after you're done unlocking and before you root.

Comment: @Compro01 Doing the backup before unlocking, yepp. I never tried that way, and it *should* not break something on restore (i.e. overwriting/removing the "root work"). With your permission, I'll include that directly with the answer.

Comment: Specifying the path to backup doesn't work with my device moto-x instead after confirming the backup on device, it creates backup with name backup.ab in current directory. The version of adb that I have is 1.0.32.

Comment: @DivKis01 `backup.ab` is the default name *if not specified otherwise*. I've never heard the `-f` parameter was ignored. Are you sure you hadn't a typo in?

Comment: @Izzy: Yeah I tried couple of times and there was no typo.

Comment: Sorry to read that. Seems your device has a buggy ADB implementation then. Which leaves to always rename the `backup.ab` after its creation – just a work-around, but better than nothing.

Comment: You write " (which means: all data and user-installed apps are gone -- which you can work around on Android 4.0+ performing an adb backup" <--- That's not such a workaround because it dosen't make an image, it makes a compressed file with the files and folders. So data recovery is very limited.

Comment: "WARNING: adb backup is deprecated and may be removed in a future release"

Comment: also for many people it doesn't work https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143367/creating-a-backup-with-adb-results-in-41-byte-file e.g. it just creates a 40-something byte file

Comment: @barlop That 41 bytes file happens for apps that opted out of backup. Which were not that common when this answer was written. Today I agree: that flag is totally over-used, and more often for the wrong reasons than not.

Answer (score 1):

It "shouldn't" change anything other than adding permission to `su`, and perhaps adding Superuser permissions app and busybox. It really depends on what method you use, though, there could be glitches that might delete something.

Comment: if rooting includes unlocking the boot loader then it might wipe the data

Answer (score 0):

I have rooted before and it doesn't erase anything.

Answer (score 0):

No Rooting does not erase anything in most of the cases, it instead provides you with extraordinary backup capabilities.

When you're rooted, you can backup almost anything (user apps, system apps, all app data, call logs, SMS, game progress, Wi-Fi access points and more) that can be easily and seamlessly restored in case of a factory reset or otherwise so loss of the data.

Comment: Some guides will point out that to root you need to unlock the boot loader, so they consider that as part of the process, and consider that "on some devices rooting requires to first unlock the bootloader -- and that usually includes a factory-reset (which means: all data and user-installed apps are gone"

Answer (score 0):

I root devices often. Rooting does not erase anything but if the rooting method does not apply properly, your motherboard can get locked or damaged.

It's always preferred to take backup before doing anything.

You can get your contacts from your email account but notes and tasks are stored in phone memory by default.

Also, after rooting you can install Clockworkmod recovery but do not wipe anything.

Comment: if rooting includes unlocking the boot loader then it might wipe the data