# Stock Nexus 4 stuck in bootloop

Tags: adb, nexus-4, data-recovery, boot-loop, unbricking

My Nexus 4 suddenly went into bootloop today after getting drained last night. 
I tried booting into recovery mode, but as it is not rooted or unlocked, fastboot and adb sideload do not work. I want to recover my data, is it possible?

What should I do? Please help!

Comment: Have you checked with our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for first aid? Did that help?

Comment: I have cleaned up the comments here again and on the answer.  Use this comment space for relevant clarifications and such only.

Comment: @MatthewRead It seems you have also deleted legit discussion on the answer below and that too selectively.

Comment: I tried to summarize.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the toolkit needed to help alleviate your bootloop. Read the whole thread to fully understand what is going on.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/toolkit-wugs-nexus-root-toolkit-v1-8-2-t2015469

You'll be able to root your device, fix your problem, then if wanted you can relock your device or install a custom ROM.
I used this on my Nexus 7, when I accidentally wiped everything (turned it into a paper weight). There were other ways to fix, but the toolkit is by far the easiest.

Hope this helps and Good Luck!

Comment: how can I take a backup without unlocking the bootloader(and with that wiping my data)?

Comment: @SumitJain Unlocking the bootloader or installing a ROM will erase data, but rooting shouldnt erase/wipe anything. For doing a backup before unlocking bootloader through adb use this cmd: `adb backup –apk –shared –all –f /<location of backup.ab>` Then to restore use this cmd: `adb restore /<location of backup.ab>`. Those cmds were pulled from this link: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44574/does-rooting-erase-anything

Comment: Also take a look at this link. *http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979* You might have to read it twice. It's a lot of info, but you'll have working knowledge of adb and fastboot. BTW, the toolkit should have had adb and fastboot as part of the program. If not, then download from the link I provided.  reflash boot.img(kernel) from FASTBOOT. That won't erase anything. Power the Nexus up into the boot loader, select fast boot, hook it to the PC, enter the commands. You don't need to be rooted or boot loader unlocked to use FASTBOOT.