# root device install again

Tags: applications

I want to root my s4 phone I have some apps on it which are no longer are availeble for download, do I have to reinstall them (in other words some programs are lost)

Hans

Comment: Rooting doesn't wipe your data.

Comment: But if you also have to unlock the bootloader see this question - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44574/does-rooting-erase-anything

Answer (score 0):

If you just root your phone and do not flash a custom rom you won't need to reinstall all those apps.

If you are planning to flash a custom rom you will need to backup all those apps. For backing up system app i use es file explorer to go to root> system folder then to apps you will see all the system apps installed in your device copy those apps in your sd card and after you flash your rom you can reinstall those apps . No need to download those apps

Answer (score 0):

Though rooting itself should not erase any data, it's always good to have a backup available in case things go wrong: "Better safe than sorry". So:

If you're just interested in the apps (but not their data), take a look at helpers like [AppMonster]([Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager), [AppWererabbit Backup](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aw.AppWererabbit), and [comparable apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_132). They can grap the `.apk` files of installed apps, and "back them up" to your SD card – so you can later re-install them from the `.apk` files directly.

You could also do that manually without the help of any app. `.apk` files are stored in `/data/app`. Without root privileges, you are not allowed to list the contents of that directory; but if you know the names of the `.apk` files, you can access them. In case you're running Linux on your computer, [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) lists the complete paths to those files in the device documentation it creates. Without that, `adb dumpsys package` provides the necessary data; watch out for the keyword `codePath` in its output.

Having the "codePath": `adb pull <codePath> <appname.apk>` would pick the `.apk` file and copy it to your computer.