# Read adopted and encrypted SD card with external SD reader?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, encryption, internal-sd

My Moto G5 sd reader doe not work anymore, and does not read the SD card that was adopted and encrypted. I want to access the sd card to save the data/pics etc.

I thought that I could use an external SD reader, and that the phone would recognize that this is the "internal" card, and hence give access to the data. It does not seem to work: using a file reader like `amaze`, I see the `OTG` option, but nothing happens? Which steps could I do? Note my phone is not rooted.

Thanks!

PS: an alternative would be to read the SD card in my Linux machine, and follow the instructions from this [page](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage), [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135803/corrupt-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage) or [this guide](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html). My understanding is that I would need to root my phone, and hence potentially loose all data anyway.

Comment: you are right, you will lose data when rooting with common bootloader unlocking method. you need root access to get a copy of /data/misc/vold. try to root with Kingoroot (with locked bootloader) or try to get backup with QPST +  HDDRawCopy (no root required) https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/how-to-backup-qualcomm-phone-root-t3570178

Comment: OTG mounts are different from block mounts. the card reader will work with other MicroSD Card, but it can not handle encryption of adopted storage

Comment: @alecxs, getting back to this after trying ohter solutions, could you elaborate a little on the Kingoroot vs QPST + HDDRawCopy methods? I'm a very beginner, so a few detailed steps would be very welcome as answer! I am also confused as some posts say roooting would not destroy data? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44574/does-rooting-erase-anything Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: unlocking bootloader will trigger factory reset, so you need to find a solution with locked bootloader (Kingoroot for rooting / QPST for backup)