# how can I mount a ab backup file from windows? And would I be able to point an undelete program on it?

Tags: images

I see this [Does rooting erase anything?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44574/does-rooting-erase-anything)  about making an ab backup file.

how can I mount an ab backup file from windows? And would I be able to run an undelete program on it or on the image?

I see this question [How do I open a .ab file on my computer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216509/how-do-i-open-a-ab-file-on-my-computer)  but it doesn't answer what i'm asking because he is asking and was understood to be asking specifically about some firefox tabs.

Comment: "mounting" is a linux thing. only block drives can mounted (or disk image files of drives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android backup files created via `adb backup` are no images, they are more comparable to ZIP files. Only existing files are included into the backup file. Deleted files can not be included in such an Android backup.

Therefore you will never be able to run an undelete program on an adb backup file.

The only backup files that would make sense to use an undelete program on are NANDroid backup files as those backups files contain one or more whole partition(s).

Comment: TWRP create tar backup of `/data` partition, not an image backup. That needs to be done manually using `dd` or `adb pull`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: OK an ab file isn't an image, it's a compressed file, like a zip file. How do you open an ab file?  7-zip can't recognise it

Comment: @barlop there you go: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/96277